# vhost is inheriting other routes

Tags: express, vhosts

I´m trying to use a different set of routes for each vhost

```
module.exports = function(app) {

    app.use(vhost('www.example.com', exampleRoutes))
    app.use(vhost('*.example.com', subdomainRoutes))

}
```

My problem is that www.example is also using the routes from **subdomainRoutes**
I need to somehow specify that if I´m under www then only the **exampleRoutes** should work

update. looks like I can use a regexp. I will need something like

not(www.example.com) but I´m terrible with regexp :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

laving this here in case someone needs it.

```
const regex = new RegExp('^(?!.*www.example.*).*$');
app.use(vhost(regex, subdomainRoutes))
```